# How to set a state of an array of object inside an array of objects in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, state, setstate

I'm trying to set a state inside an array of object inside another array of object. I tried a lot of things but i can't find the good solution.

Here's my array:

```
this.state = {
  Pages: [
    {
      image: undefined,
      audio: undefined,
      audioName: undefined,
      subtitles: 'up',
      Langs: [
        {
          lang: 'fr_FR',
          text: '',
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I'm want to modify this.state.Pages[i].Langs[y].lang or .text value.
Does some have an idea ?

Comment: How do you set your state? Inside a constructor (or anything else, when the component is created) or a function like a `setState`? Note that `setState` function work on one level of nested objects.

Comment: With the setState function. Then how to set directly one object Langs in my array ?

Comment: is it really so?? only one level nested

Comment: A bit complex. Get from the pages array the one you need to modify and it's index. Then use `array.map()` in  the `Langs` array and in that callback use conditional logic to either return the same language object or the modified object with the new text value. Finally add create a new pages array and replace the previous item with the new one (created with the `array.map`) using the index you stored previously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a copy of the `Pages` and `Pages[i].Langs` arrays, and create a copy of the `Pages[i].Langs[y]` object and overwrite the `lang` or `text` property.

**Example**

```
changeText = (i, y, text) => {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    const Pages = [...previousState.Pages];
    const Langs = [...Pages[i].Langs];

    Langs[y] = { ...Langs[y], text };
    Pages[i] = { ...Pages[i], Langs };

    return { Pages };
  });
};
```

Comment: @Tholle is it like setState wont work for multiple nested object?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala It works, but the more nested the state is, the harder it gets to get right.

Answer (score 2):

At this level of nesting I suggest you to use the [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) library:

```
import produce from "immer"

this.setState((oldState) => {
  return produce(oldState, draftState => {
    draftState.Pages.Langs.push({ lang: 'it_IT', text: 'foo' })
  })
})
```

The power of immer is that you can modify the draft as you want, without touching the old state.